# Appending traceback.format_exc() to a list is adding "\" to single quotes (')

Tags: python

I am assigning the stack trace variable `traceback.format_exc()` to a list as below ,strange thing I notice is after appending ,all the single quotes(`'`) get escaped (`\'`) as can be seen from the output below.

I looked on google @https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/336 and tried to assign `(traceback.format_exc(), sys.getfilesystemencoding()` which didn't work either,am very curious why is this happening and how to fix this?

```
import traceback
clonedRadarsdetailslist = []
clonedRadardetails = {}
try:
    #raise 
    (updateproblemoutput,updateproblempassfail) = r.UpdateProblem(problemID=newRadarID, componentName=componentName, componentVersion=componentVersion,assigneeID=assignee,state=state,substate=substate,milestone=milestone, category=category,priority=priority,resolution=re_solution )
except:
    clonedRadardetails['updatedFailedReason'] = traceback.format_exc()
    clonedRadarsdetailslist.append(clonedRadardetails)

print clonedRadarsdetailslist
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 ['{\'clonedRadar\': 40171867, \'clonedStatus\': \'PASS\', \'clonedRadarFinalStatus\': \'PASS\', \'updatedFailedReason\': \'Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File "./cloneradar.py", line 174, in clone\\n    (updatetitleoutput,updatetitlepassfail) = r.UpdateProble(problemID=newRadarID,title=title )\\nAttributeError: \\\'RadarWS\\\' object has no attribute \\\'UpdateProble\\\'\\n\', \'clonedRadarFinalStatusReason\': \'N/A\', \'updateStatus\': \'FAIL\', \'clonedStatusfailReason\': \'N/A\'}', '{\'clonedRadar\': 40171867, \'clonedStatus\': \'PASS\', \'clonedRadarFinalStatus\': \'PASS\', \'updatedFailedReason\': \'Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File "./cloneradar.py", line 174, in clone\\n    (updatetitleoutput,updatetitlepassfail) = r.UpdateProble(problemID=newRadarID,title=title )\\nAttributeError: \\\'RadarWS\\\' object has no attribute \\\'UpdateProble\\\'\\n\', \'clonedRadarFinalStatusReason\': \'N/A\', \'updateStatus\': \'FAIL\', \'clonedStatusfailReason\': \'N/A\'}']
```

Comment: `"./cloneradar.py"` is wrong, replace all `"` letter for `printable version`. `>>> s = " "` to  `>>> repr(s)`  output is `"' '"` so use single seperator char. Like `("""%s"""%traceback.format_exc()).replace("\"","'")`

Comment: @dsgdfg - that didn't help...its going wrong while appending `clonedRadardetails` to `clonedRadarsdetailslist` ,not sure why,do you have any pointers?

Comment: If you use the   `"` character and `'` character in a string, the escape character is added to each separator. The filename changes your seperator. the example I gave is running, assign the correction to a variable if it doesn't work. Like `v = ("""%s"""%traceback.format_exc()).replace("\"","'") ` than `clonedRadardetails['updatedFailedReason'] = v`

Comment: @dsgdfg -   After taking your suggestion,clonedRadardetails look like `{'clonedRadar': 40174938, 'clonedStatus': 'PASS', 'clonedRadarFinalStatus': 'PASS', 'updatedFailedReason': "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File './cloneradar.py', line 174, in clone\n    (updatetitleoutput,updatetitlepassfail) = r.UpdateProble(problemID=newRadarID,title=title )\nAttributeError: 'RadarWS' object has no attribute 'UpdateProble'\n", 'clonedRadarFinalStatusReason': 'N/A', 'updateStatus': 'FAIL', 'clonedStatusfailReason': 'N/A'}` ,notice the double quotes `"` around Traceback for `updatedFailedReason` key

Comment: I changed it to `v = ('%s'%traceback.format_exc()).replace("\"","'")` ,it still wraps around double quotes `"`

Comment: @dsgdfg - are you sure what you said is  the root-cause of the problem? how come appending `clonedRadardetails` to `clonedRadarsdetailslist` is causing this beyond me?

Comment: In your example code, you're appending a *dictionary* to the list, but in the output you show the contents of the list is a *string* .  The output example is consistent with `str` being called on the dict before it's appended to the list.  For example `str({'a': 'foo "bar"'})` results in `'{\'a\': \'foo "bar"\'}'`

Comment: @snakecharmerb - you are exactly right, thanks for helping to root cause..how do I unstring the dictionary ?

Comment: Show us the real code so we can see where it gets stringified? As a workaround you can call `ast.literal_eval` on the string but ideally you want to stop it being stringified in the first place, or at least understand why your code is doing it.